# Deleting a record from SQLite using spinner and updating spinner values in Android not working properly

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner

I have a spinner which has 3 values from SQLite database one dummy and 2 real

I select one item and I delete one item

When I am trying to delete the next one spinner is not updating its values. The value its there even if I reload activity.

method to load data to spinner and I call it whenever I delete item:

```
private void LoadSpinnerData(ArrayList<String> list)
{     
    seasonslist.add(0,"Please Select");
    // Creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    MySpin.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Here is my delete method

```
mHelper.deleteItem(Id);
Selected_id=null;
List = mHelper.getAllData();
LoadSpinnerData(List);
```

And here my spinner item select

```
 MySpin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            if(position>0)
            {
                Selected_id = (int) (long) id;
            }

        }

    });
```

My delete function is

```
public boolean deleteItem(int id)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete("mytable","item_id"+"="+Integer.toString(id),null)>0;
}
```

Comment: Check if you delete successfully your item from your db table!

Comment: Can you your method: `getAllData()`

Answer (score 0):

After deletion instead of adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); you can use the following code.

```
adapter.remove(position);
```

the position here will the item_id matching from the database.

this will check the id from database and will delete the position of the spinner list item based on the index position of spinner list.

So delete from spinner item first and then from the database or vice versa